# How to format table cells in MS Word based on the format of the text in each individual cell

Tags: vba, text, ms-word, formatting

I have several word documents to modify on a weekly basis that contain tables ranging from 1 x 6 up to 6 x 10 in size. All of the cells in all of the tables contain text, some of the cells contain text that is bold, some cells have mixed formatting(bold and standard), and the rest of the cells are standard.

I am trying to find code for a macro to change the background color in every cell that contains bold text, even it it also contains standard text.
 This is pretty simple and I was able to find several different solutions for the this, but I run into the following issue in all code examples I have tried.

All of the examples I have tried will change the background color in all of the cells containing only bold text, but ignores the cells with mixed formatting(bold and standartd). I have tried several different ways to work around this but just don't have the knowledge to overcome the issue.

Here is a sample of the code I am using:

```
Sub Fill_Bold_Cell()

Dim myCell
For Each myCell In Selection.Tables(1).Range.Cells

    If myCell.Range.Font.Bold = True Then

        myCell.Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -603923969

    End If
Next myCell

End Sub
```

Any help with this issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pair of procedures should do the job.

```
Sub Fill_Bold_Cell()

    Dim Tbl As Table
    Dim myCell

    For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each myCell In Tbl.Range.Cells
            If FindBold(myCell.Range) Then
                myCell.Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -603923969
            End If
        Next myCell
    Next Tbl
End Sub

Private Function FindBold(Rng As Range) As Boolean

    With Rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Text = ""
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute
        FindBold = .Found
    End With
End Function
```

As you see, I have kept your code almost unchanged. The critical part which was giving you a problem was moved into a separate function. In the way, the part which is good doesn't get contaminated by the part that isn't.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This worked very well for my purposes.